# Bodymovin shows wilder animation

Tags: javascript, animation, after-effects, bodymovin

We have created some animation with Body Movin, all of them works great.
The problem we have now is, the Body Movin animation animate really wild compared to what it supposed to animate.

Original Animation:
[image: shaking]

Bodymovin Animation:
[image: shaking-fail]

You can test and play around here:
https://codepen.io/albertdp/project/editor/AmbRgM

I am calling it the same way it has in the demo.

```
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('bm'),
  renderer: 'canvas',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  path: 'data.json'
})
```

Please let me know if you ever encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is three way to render the animation, maybe you can try :

```
    var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
            container: document.getElementById('bm'),
            renderer: 'svg',
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            path: 'data.json'
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that but still not working. We found out that the actual problem was we are using programming function on AE to random the movements. After we remove that, and change to static animation, everything run smoothly